# Cannot set and Activity as the first to be opened - Session Manager in Android

Tags: android, session, android-activity

I'm building and application for Android and my intention is to keep the user logged in even after I close the app. I'm using this class called SessionManager to deal with it:

```
public class SessionManager {
    // Shared Preferences
    SharedPreferences pref;

    // Editor for Shared preferences
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    // Context
    Context _context;

    // Shared pref mode
    int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

    // Sharedpref file name
    private static final String PREF_NAME = "AndroidHivePref";

    // All Shared Preferences Keys
    private static final String IS_LOGIN = "IsLoggedIn";

    // User name (make variable public to access from outside)
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";

    // Email address (make variable public to access from outside)
    public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";

    // Constructor
    public SessionManager(Context context){
        this._context = context;
        pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = pref.edit();
    }

    /**
     * Create login session
     * */
    public void createLoginSession(String name, String email){
        // Storing login value as TRUE
        editor.putBoolean(IS_LOGIN, true);

        // Storing name in pref
        editor.putString(KEY_NAME, name);

        // Storing email in pref
        editor.putString(KEY_EMAIL, email);

        // commit changes
        editor.commit();
    }

    /**
     * Check login method wil check user login status
     * If false it will redirect user to login page
     * Else won't do anything
     * */
    public void checkLogin(){
        // Check login status
        if(!this.isLoggedIn()){
            // user is not logged in redirect him to Login Activity
            Intent i = new Intent(_context, MainActivity.class);
            // Closing all the Activities
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            // Add new Flag to start new Activity
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            // Staring Login Activity
            _context.startActivity(i);
        }

    }



    /**
     * Get stored session data
     * */
    public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(){
        HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
        // user name
        user.put(KEY_NAME, pref.getString(KEY_NAME, null));

        // user email id
        user.put(KEY_EMAIL, pref.getString(KEY_EMAIL, null));

        // return user
        return user;
    }

    /**
     * Clear session details
     * */
    public void logoutUser(){
        // Clearing all data from Shared Preferences
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();

        // After logout redirect user to Loing Activity
        Intent i = new Intent(_context, MainActivity.class);
        // Closing all the Activities
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        // Add new Flag to start new Activity
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        // Staring Login Activity
        _context.startActivity(i);
    }

    /**
     * Quick check for login
     * **/
    // Get Login State
    public boolean isLoggedIn(){
        return pref.getBoolean(IS_LOGIN, false);
    }
}
```

In the login activity I added this code lines:

```
SessionManager session;
session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
```

And after the credentials entered are compared with the ones stored in the database I do this:

```
session.createLoginSession("Username", "email_address");
```

This is the screen I want to set as the one to be opened if the user is logged in:

```
public class MainScreen  extends AppCompatActivity {

    Switch list_toggle;
    String user_id,username,status;
    boolean ischecked;

    public static String Name;

    SessionManager session;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_screen);

        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
        session.checkLogin();

        final TextView textView4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        final TextView textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        list_toggle = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.mySwitch);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {

            username = extras.getString("USER_NAME");
            user_id = extras.getString("USER_ID");
            status = extras.getString("STATUS");
        }

        if (status.contentEquals("Available")){

            ischecked = true;
        }
        else{
            ischecked = false;
        }

        textView4.setText(Html.fromHtml(status));
        list_toggle.setChecked(ischecked);


        String[] parts = username.split(" ");
        String name = parts[0];
        String surname = parts[1];

        textView3.setText(Html.fromHtml("Hi, " + name + " "));

        Name = name;


        list_toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {

                    textView4.setText(Html.fromHtml("Available"));

                } else {

                    textView4.setText(Html.fromHtml("Unavailable"));

                }
            }
        });

        //Tabs

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Orders"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Past Orders"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("More"));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
                (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {


            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

So checkLogin() is supposed to check if the user is logged in in the application, if not, he will be redirected to the login activity (MainActivity).

This is the AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mvaguimaraes.bt">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".MainScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

        </activity>



        <activity android:name=".OrderDetails"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

So I tried to set "MainScreen" as the activity to be opened first:

```
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
```

If there's no-one logged in checkLogin() will redirect to "MainApplication" activity. But this is not working. Somehow, the application crashes if I set MainScreen as the first activity. Is it because I'm sending data (username, user_id, status) from the login activity to this MainScreen activity and using it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

save a value when user register himself first time and enters in the app

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Login", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putString("isUserRegistered", "Y");
        editor.commit();
```

Now get this value in your SplashActivity and compare the value `isUserRegistered` if it equals to **Y** forward him to MainActivity.else signin page 
If user signs out clear the value of `isUserRegistered`.

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("Login", 0);
preferences.edit().remove("isUserRegistered").commit();
```

being more clear write this code in your splashscreen's `onCreate(...)`

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Login", MODE_PRIVATE);
    final String s = pref.getString("isUserRegistred", null);
    //Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this,s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // This method will be executed once the timer is over
            // Start your app main activity
            if (s != null) {
                if (s.contains("Y")) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();

                }
            } else {
                Intent j = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, SignIn.class);
                j.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                startActivity(j);
                finish();
            }
            // close this activity

        }
    }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
```

If you do not have a SplashScreen just create an Activity and put the above code in its `onCreate(...)` set it to `Launcher` Activity in the `Manifest.xml`

Comment: Do you know that you can store bool in SharedPreferences?